# How do I return multiple rows, when I only have one unique variable per row to use in the where clause?

Tags: mysql

I currently have a very simple MySQL query like this;

```
     SET  @recordID     = 60749;    
        SELECT netID, ID, recordID, team
          FROM NetLog
         WHERE recordID =  @recordID;
```

The variable recordID is unique for each row, and is the only variable available to get the needed row.

But now I also need to return any other rows that have the same 'team' value as the original row. I tried this with several variations but it always returns; "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row"

```
SET  @recordID  = 60749;
SELECT a.netID, a.ID, a.recordID, a.team,
    (SELECT b.recordID FROM NetLog b WHERE b.team = a.team AND b.recordID <> a.recordID) as rID
          FROM NetLog a
         WHERE a.recordID =  @recordID;
```

I would like to do this in one query if possible.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION` to combine the queries.

```
WITH mainRow AS (
    SELECT netID, ID, recordID, team
    FROM NetLog
    WHERE recordID = @recordID
)
SELECT * FROM mainRow
UNION
SELECT b.netID, b.ID, b.recordID, b.team
FROM NetLog AS b
JOIN mainRow AS a ON b.team = a.team AND b.recordID <> a.recordID
```

Comment: I'm new but not that new even so I've never seen a 'With' like that. Apparently phpMyAdmin has not either it gives me an error. Am I missing code?

Comment: It's a [Common Table Expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) It requires MySQL 8.x

Comment: That explains it. I way back on MySQL 5.x is there a work around?

Comment: You could just use it as a subquery in the `JOIN` in place of `mainRow`